# Why does writing to csv file using print split one line into two?

Tags: vba, csv

```
Public Function WriteToFile(xyz As String)
    Dim PathToFile As String
    Dim FileNumber As Long

    Open PathToFile For Output As #FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, xyz
End Function
```

String xyz is written over two rows instead of one.

Is there any restriction on length of xyz?

Comment: What does "is written over two rows instead of one" mean?

Comment: @FaneDaru string contains comma separated values. This data should be written in one row in different columns. But instead after certain length of string in written in first row remaining data is written in next one

Answer (score 0):

Mention cell as well to write e.g.

Cells(1, 1)= xyz

It will write in 1st row and first column

Comment: My code works until certain length of string `xyz`, so I want to know is their any length limit or why it's not working for a string of length 55000

Comment: The limit of `Open   For Output` looks to be 2GB (for resulted .txt file). Look, please, to my second variant (in my answer) for a size bigger than 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testWriteToFile()
    WriteToFile "abcd", "Your file Full Name"
    TextStreamWrite "abcde", "Your second file Full Name"
End Sub
Public Function WriteToFile(xyz As String, PathToFile As String)
    FreeFile 1

    Open PathToFile For Output As #1
      Print #1, xyz
    Close #1
End Function
```

For sizes over 2 GB use this code:

```
Private Function TextStreamWrite(xyz As String, PathToFile As String)
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
    Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
    Dim fs, f, ts, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fs.CreateTextFile PathToFile
    Set f = fs.GetFile(PathToFile)
    Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault)
        ts.Write xyz
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Do not forget to replace "Your file Full Name" and "Your second file Full Name" with your files path...

Comment: But size is not exciding 2 GB. It's less than 1 MB

Comment: Did you try the second proposed solution? I never tried by myself the limit in discussion. I've just read about it, not having such a need... But you did not say anything about .csv... How do you prepare the string to be put in the .csv file?

Comment: @rs4: But you did not say anything about .csv... How do you prepare the string to be put in the .csv file? My example answers your question. It puts a big string inside a .txt/.csv file. But your problem looks to be the way of building that string...

Comment: @rs4: Can you post here the way of the string in discussion building? Maybe I can help with a fast solution (using arrays and working only in memory)...

Comment: CSV is mentioned in question title. If you have comma separated values in a string and you print that in a CSV file it will be converted in a row of different columns as per commas

Comment: @rs4:  I meant .CSV preparation... I thought that the string was well prepared and the single problem was what you expressed in your question. Having a big number of rows and columns, the most efficient way would be to load all the range in an array and then to create comma separated slices, to be print in the .CSV file row by row.